# elasticsearch nested functionScoreQuery cannot access parent properties

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a type in elasticsearch that looks like this:

```
    "hotel" : {    
         "field" : 1,    
         "rooms" : [
            {
           "type" : "single",
           "magicScore" : 1
            }, 
            {
            "type" : "double",
            "magicScore" : 2
            }
        ] 
  }
```

where rooms is of type nested. I sort using a nested functionScoreQuery:

```
{
  "query" : {
    "filtered" : {
      "query" : {
        "nested" : {
          "query" : {
            "function_score" : {
              "filter" : {
                "match_all" : { }
              },
              "functions" : [ {
                "script_score" : {
                  "script" : "return doc['hotel.field'].value"      
                }
              } ]
            }
          },
          "path" : "rooms",
          "score_mode" : "max"
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Problem is hotel.field returns 0 always. Is there a way to access the parent field inside a nested query? I know I can always pack the field inside the nested document but its a hack not a solution. Would using a dismax query help me? https://discuss.elastic.co/t/nested-value-on-function-score/29935

The query I am actually using looks something like this:

```
{
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "nested" : {
          "query" : {
            "function_score" : {
              "query" : {
                "not" : {
                  "query" : {
                    "terms" : {
                      "rooms.type" : [ "single", "triple" ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "functions" : [ {
                "script_score" : {
                  "script" : {
                    "inline" : "return doc['rooms.magicScore'].value;",
                    "lang" : "groovy",
                    "params" : {
                      "ratings" : {
                        "sample" : 0.5
                      },
                      "variable" : [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -0.5, -2.5]
                    }
                  }
                }
              } ],
              "score_mode" : "max"
            }
          },
          "path" : "rooms"
        }
      },
      "filter" : {
        "bool" : {
          "filter" : [ {
            "bool" : {
              "should" : [ {
                "term" : {
                  "cityId" : "166"
                }
              }, {
                "term" : {
                  "cityId" : "165"
                }
              } ]
            }
          }, {
            "nested" : {
              "query" : {
                "not" : {
                  "query" : {
                    "terms" : {
                      "rooms.type" : [ "single", "triple" ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "path" : "rooms"
            }
          } ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is to access for example the cityId inside the function_score query which is nested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is why are you accessing the parent values in a `nested` query. Once you are in the `nested` context, you cannot access parent fields or other fields from other `nested` fields.

From [the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-query.html):

> The nested clause “steps down” into the nested comments field. It no longer has access to fields in the root document, nor fields in any other nested document.

So, rewrite your queries so that the `nested` part touches the fields in that `nested` field and anything else is accessed **outside** the `nested` part.

Comment: Hi, how would I score this? I need to add up the score from the nested function score query and from the query on the parent fields.

Comment: Please, post the query you are **actually using**. The one you posted seems to be just a sample.

Comment: Hi, I edited the question to add the query I am actually using

Comment: @m1416 so, in the script you need both `rooms.magicScore` (which is `nested`) **AND** `cityId` which is not `nested`?

Comment: correct, this is exactly what I am trying to do. I have tried using _ctx.source but this makes the query go from 50ms to 3s. Is there a way I can rewrite the query so two scores are calculated and then add them up?

Comment: Hm. Just an idea, without actually testing it: remove the `nested` at the top of the query, then in your `function_score` use two functions - one for your nested query and using a script return **just** the value you are interested and another function that uses a script to return the value from the "root" object. Set the `function_score` to have `score_mode: sum` and see if it works.

Comment: Hi, the suggestion you are giving will not actually work. I cannot match "scopes" inside the function_score query, I have tried this before.

Comment: I found the following online http://grokbase.com/t/gg/elasticsearch/148v8fjfve/access-nested-field-inside-function-query-with-script-score which would involve reindexing everything